# Insert data from one table to another table where two columns do not match

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables.

```
TABLE A
ID | LABEL|PARENT_ID| VISIBLE | HIDEABLE
1  |SPORTS|   1     |    1    |    1
2  | FOOD |   1     |    1    |    0
3  | CARS |   1     |    0    |    1
4  |TRAVEL|   1     |    1    |    1
5  | LOVE |   1     |    1    |    1
6  | OTHER|   1     |    1    |    0
7  | SHOES|   3     |    0    |    1
8  |TRAVEL|   3     |    1    |    1
9  |NATURE|   3     |    1    |    1
10 |FRIEND|   3     |    1    |    0
11 | CARS |   3     |    0    |    1
12 | LOVE |   3     |    1    |    1

TABLE B
ID | LABEL|PARENT_ID| DISPLAY_POST | DISPLAY_COMMENTS
1  |SPORTS|   1     |         1    |    1
2  | FOOD |   1     |         1    |    0
3  | CARS |   1     |         0    |    1
4  |TRAVEL|   3     |         1    |    1
```

I want to insert data into TABLE B from TABLE A with these checks:

A.LABEL <> B.LABEL AND A.VISIBLE=1 AND A.HIDEABLE=1

How can I do this?

Everything I try it returns duplicates or missing rows.

Comment: Can you also post what the end result of `TABLE B` will be after the insert action?  Also, post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for table B.  Sometimes, these operations are handled by taking advantage of unique indexes (though your conditions look like they will not allow for that)

Comment: These are example tables. But you can assume that Parent_ID are foreign keys to another third tabe

Answer (score 0):

Just use `insert . . . select` with the right conditions:

```
insert into b( . . .)
     select . . .
     from a
     where a.visible = 1 and a.hideable = 1 and
           not exists (select 1 from b2 where a.label = b2.label);
```

The `. . .` are just the list of columns for inserting.

Comment: Hi, this is the exact sort of query I am trying right now and it is not returning me some rows. I've been advised store a set of the distinct PARENT_IDs then loop through them and insert the data in the loop.

Comment: @JohnathanAu . . . An `insert` query doesn't "return rows".  It adds new rows into a table.